# BroadcastReceiver does not receive Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I wrote an app, which shows a dialog when charge lvl is 15% or low.
Problem is that on one forum I received the message that it does not work on Google Nexus S (I9023). MIUI 2.3.7c.

code for receiver is (it is registered in manifest):

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW))
    {
        try
        {
            context.startService(myIntent);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){Toast.makeText(context, "Problem with Starting a Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
```

In service I register receiver with filter Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
code for service in is:

```
...
if (batteryLevel == mLowLevelAlarm)
{
    if (prefView.getBoolean(PREF_LOW_CHARGE_ON, true))
    {
         myIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, BatteryLow.class);
         myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
...
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem? 
thx

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am facing similar problem :(
If you found a solution, please add it as answer.